# Generate items for a select with bootstrap-select and angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-select

I want to use the bootstrap-selector to get a dropdown menu with items from a REST-API.
The ul list is working fine but there are no items in the selector.

Update:
It also works if I remove the class selectpicker, so bootstrap-select is the problem. Could it be that bootstrap-select does not like dynamicly changed options?

```js
<div>
//tried this
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option *ngFor="let race of races">{{race.name}}</option>
  </select>


//this is working fine
  <ul *ngFor="let race of races">
    <li>{{race.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Java, did you log the result from the API call in the component.ts file? Maybe you are not getting anything of not waiting long enough before the 'races' is displayed. Can you add it here?

Comment: the strange part is, it works if I remove class="selectpicker" but with its an empty selector.

Comment: What is your selectpicker class look like?

Comment: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/